# Wordpress audio player add class randomly using Audio Album plugin

Tags: plugins, css, audio

so i have this player displaying a progress bar, but when i click play, a "style" is added to the progress bar class on several span class. It's either width: 0 or width: 197.

I'm using the Audio Album plugin which from what i understood is based on the native Wordpress player.
But i can't find what and how those "style" are attributed.

Here's the address: http://www.zeekray.com/wordpress/audio/

If anyone can help that'll be great :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the behavior with just native player? If it's specific to plugin it would be better aimed at its developers/support.

Comment: Yeah i'm using three different players but only this one is causing problems.